# Wildcard replacement in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

For example, I have this script:

```
var text = '09';

$( 'p.container' ).html( function ( i, html ) {
    var regexp, replacement;

    regexp = RegExp( '(' + text + ')', 'gi' );
    replacement = '<span class="highlight">$1</span>';

    return html.replace( regexp, replacement );
});
```

The container contains these values :

- 0232**09**
- 232332
- 092323
- 8372**09**

Now I only want to highlight the value which has `09` at the end (please note that the third value contains `09` at the beginning), how do I compare it? Something like

```
html.replace( "****09", replacement );
```

Edit:

The container contains these values :

- 0232**09**
- 2323**08**
- 092323
- 8372**09**

Now I only want to highlight the value which has the first character = `0` in the last 2 characters of each value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bae3ufs5/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Oh, that is perfect! Would you mind adding it as an answer? By the way, can I ask one more question? How about I only want to compare only the left character of the two right most characters of the string?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bae3ufs5/2/ ?

Comment: @hoangnnm It's worth noting that `*` is not the regex wildcard character. The period `.` is the wildcard character--matches any character once. The asterisk `*` is a quantifier, which means 0 or more. So it matches any number of consecutive occurrences of the preceding character. `a*` would match `''` or `'aaaaa'`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny You're so amazing!

Comment: @nbrooks thanks, that's very informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a regex like

```js
var text = '09';

var regexp = RegExp('(\d*' + text + ')(\\s|$)', 'gi'),
  replacement = '<span class="highlight">$1</span>$2';
$('p.container').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(regexp, replacement);
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="container">023209 232332 092323 837209</p>
```